# How to add data to array in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

Assuming the following schema, I am trying to save some GeoJSON data with Mongoose

```
var simpleSchema = new Schema({
    properties:{
        name:String,
        surname:String
    },
    location : {
        type : String,
        coordinates : [ Number , Number ]
    }
});
```

This is how I try to save the document

```
var a = new simple({properties:{name:"a", surname:"b"}, location:{type:"Point", coordinates:[1, 0]}}).save(function(err){...});
```

However, what I am getting in the database is

```
ObjectId("542da9ab0882b41855ac3be0"), "properties" : { "name" : "a", "surname" : "b" }, "__v" : 0 }
```

It looks like the whole location tag and data are missing. Is this a wrong way to define a schema or a wrong way of saving the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a field named `type` in an embedded object, you need to use an object to define its type or Mongoose thinks you're defining the type of object itself.

So change your schema definition to:

```
var simpleSchema = new Schema({
    properties:{
        name:String,
        surname:String
    },
    location : {
        type : { type: String },
        coordinates : [ Number , Number ]
    }
});
```

Comment: So, this is a Mongoose "issue" and not a MongoDB?

Comment: @Dimitris Right, it's a Mongoose quirk.