# Mongoose schema updating GeoJSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have the following Mongoose schema representing a moving object

```
var vehicleSchema = new Schema({
    properties:{
        obj:String,
        name:String,
        id:String
    },
    geometry : {
        type: {type : String},
        coordinates : [ Number, Number ]
    }
});
```

and I am trying to update it with the following object and command which work flawlessly if I enter in mongo console but does not update the document when used in a node function.

This is the object to be updated:

```
var updatedVehicle = new Vehicle(
    {properties:{
        obj:"Answer",
        name:"is", 
        id:"42"
    },
    geometry:{
        type:"Point", 
        coordinates:[42,42]
    }
 })
```

And this is the update command

```
Vehicle.update(
   {$and:[
       {'properties.obj':data.properties.obj},
       {'properties.id':data.properties.id}
    ]}, 
   {$set:
       {properties:data.properties, geometry:data.geometry}
   }, 
   {upsert: true}, 
   cb
)
```

I know that Mongoose has some [quirks when it comes to GeoJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168415/how-to-add-data-to-array-in-mongoose-schema/26173287#26173287) and I hope this is just another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geometry schema property should just be set to an array of Numbers to store the coordinates, like so:

```
geometry : {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere` //some geospatial queries require this
}
```

and then query and updated as such

```
{ $set: { geometry: data.geometry.coordinates } }
```

Comment: But doesn't that deviate from the GeoJSON format? Based on that format the type field is there to store the type.

Comment: @Dimitris I haven't looked at the GeoJSON spec, but mongo doesn't require setting the the type property, in fact the schema is just a mongoose abstraction it's not reflected on mongoose except for certain cases like `index`. It does however require specifying the type when running a geospacial query as shown here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/

Comment: So, what I understand is that I do not need to worry about the schema as long as I have the geometry tag indexed and use the type when I do geospatial queries. 
This means that i can make a new object with just {geometry:[x,y], index:'2dsphere'}
By the way, I prefer using "testV.index({ 'geometry' : '2dsphere' });" once in the schema than adding it to every new object. 
I will do some testing and come back. ;-